# Is there a better way to get all products with the required attributes and valid values?

Tags: mysql

I want to get all the products which contain a set of required attributes from the following table structure:

```
product

uid | name
---------------
  1 | Product A
  2 | Product B
  3 | Product C


attribute_set

uid | product | attribute | attribute_value
-------------------------------------------
  1 |       1 |         2 |               4
  2 |       1 |         2 |               5
  3 |       1 |         3 |              10
  4 |       2 |         2 |               4
  5 |       2 |         3 |              10
```

For example I want to get all the products which **own attribute 2 with the values 4 and 5 and which own attribute 3 with value 10**.

To achive this I am currently using a query like this:

```
SELECT product.uid,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM attribute_set
    WHERE attribute_set.attribute = 2
    AND attribute_set.attribute_value IN (4,5)
    AND product.uid = attribute_set.product
) as counter,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM attribute_set
    WHERE attribute_set.attribute = 3
    AND attribute_set.attribute_value IN (10)
    AND product.uid = attribute_set.product
) as counter2
FROM product
LEFT JOIN attribute_set
ON product.uid = attribute_set.product
GROUP BY product.uid
HAVING counter = 2 AND counter2 = 1
```

So I have to check if the amount of the required values per attribute match the subquery counter value. This is working for me, but is there a way to do it better?

Comment: Shouldn't that work with a simple `JOIN`  on the attribute table?

Comment: Hm, what do you mean? The required attributes should also match all the required attribute values. I have edited the question title, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I have used `join` and `case` by removing sub-queries

```
SELECT p.uid,
COUNT(CASE WHEN a.attribute = 2 AND a.attribute_value IN (4,5) THEN 1 END) AS counter1,
COUNT(CASE WHEN a.attribute = 3 AND a.attribute_value IN (10)  THEN 1 END) AS counter2
FROM product p
JOIN attribute_set a ON p.uid = a.product
GROUP BY p.uid
HAVING counter1 = 2 AND counter2 = 1
```

Comment: Thank you James :). I think your solution is a way more cleaner.